# Is there a utility for Bulk SVN commits?

Tags: svn

I use `SVN` commits through command line and `Tortoise`. Often times we get a task to download a large `.jar` file from some 3rd party distribution, unpack the `.jar` (which has a bunch of files and directory structure) and commit the code into `SVN`.

The problem is that commits to this repository are limited to around 70MB for individual commits, and this `.jar` contains several hundred MB of data. So I'm forced to commit batches of files manually in large chunks, but it is a long annoying manual task open to human error (several times people miss files only to find out later). This means sifting through individual folders and synchronizing them - which ends up taking about a half days effort.

This `.jar` is updated on a semi-regular basis (maybe every 3 months or so), so we need to overwrite the old files and some of the files will have changed, be deleted, or not changed.

Is there a smarter way to do this task?

Comment: Use conventional lingua, if you want to be understood. In SVN-world **there are not** checkins, only *commits*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see at least three possible ways:

1. Ask SVN-admin to disable this (size-check) pre-commit hook for some special single user and update under this user's credentials
2. Split files into big **permanent set** of predefined changelists (`svn help cl`), commit changelists with keeping changelists (`svn ci --cl ... ----keep-changelists`) automatically, check state of WC (`svn help st`) after all commits by hand and commit a pristine remnants
3. Restructure tree: move this unpacked jar into separate dir in external repository (link with svn externals to old location) without commit-size limit

My personal preferences in choice will be 3-1-2 (I'm too lazy to do monkey-job), your mileage may vary